# How to append a rectangle in SVG/3Djs?

Tags: javascript, svg

Here is a part of code I got from some example:

```
svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")").on("click", click)
;
```

And here is what I am trying to do based on some other example:

```
var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", width)
    .style("fill", '#000');
rect.on("click", click);
```

Click works, but I cannot known where th clickable zone is located, it is not covering my chart, but is somewhere in a corner of it. So I tried to give it a colour (black in this case), but still it stay invisible.

I have also tried

```
var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", margin.left)
    .attr("y", margin.top)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .style("fill", '#000');
rect.on("click", click);
```

No better result.

Questions:

- How can I give my rectangle a colour so that I can know where it is
  on the page?
- How can I have my rectangle match the whole SVG?

EDIT: I have just realised that "onclick" works because it is also attached to the "g" , but I am still interested in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have given it a colour, #000 i.e. black.

The trouble is here

```
svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")").on("click", click)
;
```

The svg variable is not the `<svg>` element, because of chaining it's the `<g>` element, which has a transform on it so the rect is transformed.